# Android SQL User based Databases

Tags: android, database, sqlite

(New to SQL/java) I am trying to implement an app that will accept user login and save data on local SQL database.

All the implementations I have seem so far define the Database name as a
private static final String within the database helper class. I need to be able to pass a string with the user name from MainActivity to the Database helper class and create / open a database with that string name.

When I try to include a non-final String as DATABASE_NAME on following declaration it fails to run:

```
    public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
       public DBHelper(){
          super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,1);
   }
```

I am not sure if it is even possible. If not possible, then I would appreciate any suggestions on how to store data separated by different user on same app.

Thanks to all!

Providing further detail as requested. (the code is a bit messy from several experimentations....)

This is what I have in the Helper class:

```
//DATABASE NAME
SQLiteDatabase data;

//TABLE_NAME
private String TABLE_NAME;

//COLUMN ID's
private static final String KEY_ID = "ID";
private static final String KEY_Name = "name";
private static final String KEY_Gender = "gender";


public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String DATABASE_NAME) { //tried to pass DATABASE name here
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) { //Could not pass TABLE_NAME here so created the "createTable" below

}

public void createTable(String TABLE_NAME){
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            KEY_Name +" TEXT, "+KEY_Gender+" TEXT)";
    data.execSQL(createTable); //Code runs up to here on DEBUG
}
```

In the MainActivity I have this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this, "USER1");
        mDatabaseHelper.createTable("People");

    }
}
```

The event logger does not show any errors but the layout does not show on the emulator. If I do not execute the last command:

```
mDatabaseHelper.createTable("People");
```

then the layout comes in perfectly. If I debug and go line by line, the program goes into a try/catch inside ActivityThread.java:

```
if (activity != null) {
                CharSequence title = r.activityInfo.loadLabel(appContext.getPackageManager());
                Configuration config = new Configuration(mCompatConfiguration);
                if (r.overrideConfig != null) {
                    config.updateFrom(r.overrideConfig);
                }
                if (DEBUG_CONFIGURATION) Slog.v(TAG, "Launching activity "
                        + r.activityInfo.name + " with config " + config);
                Window window = null;
                if (r.mPendingRemoveWindow != null && r.mPreserveWindow) {
                    window = r.mPendingRemoveWindow;
                    r.mPendingRemoveWindow = null;
                    r.mPendingRemoveWindowManager = null;
                }
                appContext.setOuterContext(activity);
                activity.attach(appContext, this, getInstrumentation(), r.token,
                        r.ident, app, r.intent, r.activityInfo, title, r.parent,
                        r.embeddedID, r.lastNonConfigurationInstances, config,
                        r.referrer, r.voiceInteractor, window, r.configCallback);

                if (customIntent != null) {
                    activity.mIntent = customIntent;
                }
                r.lastNonConfigurationInstances = null;
                checkAndBlockForNetworkAccess();
                activity.mStartedActivity = false;
                int theme = r.activityInfo.getThemeResource();
                if (theme != 0) {
                    activity.setTheme(theme);
                }

                activity.mCalled = false;
                if (r.isPersistable()) {
                    mInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(activity, r.state, r.persistentState);
                } else {
                    mInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(activity, r.state);
                }
                if (!activity.mCalled) {
                    throw new SuperNotCalledException(
                        "Activity " + r.intent.getComponent().toShortString() +
                        " did not call through to super.onCreate()");
                }
                r.activity = activity;
            }
            r.setState(ON_CREATE);

            mActivities.put(r.token, r);

        } catch (SuperNotCalledException e) {
            throw e;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (!mInstrumentation.onException(activity, e)) {
                throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Unable to start activity " + component
                    + ": " + e.toString(), e);
            }
```

This happens when I execute this code line:

```
data.execSQL(createTable);
```

Comment: Please explain **in detail** what "it fails to run" means. Does it fail to compile? Does it crash when you run it (and, if so, what does the stack trace in Logcat show)?

Comment: I tried to clarify further on top. Glad to provide more detail if needed. Thanks for the fast reply.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        KEY_Name +" TEXT, "+KEY_Gender+" TEXT)";
```

Will work once the first time that the App is run. You will then have an error because the App will then attempt to create the table which already exists.

Changing to

```
String createTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        KEY_Name +" TEXT, "+KEY_Gender+" TEXT)";
```

Will circumvent that failure. Which is more than likely the issue you are encountering.